# Calling NSRunLoop methods in applicationDidBecomeActive causes system to not respond

Tags: objective-c, ios

When my iOS app is activated, on clicking a file the app supports (FTA), I want to display a modal view in applicationDidBecomeActive. Since I want the control back, when the modal view is dismissed, I use NSRunLoop and a flag to detect the view is dismissed. Please see the attached code. When the [NSRunloop runUntilDate] is invoked, my view is displayed but behind the current view and does not respond to keyboard/mouse actions. Any ideas what is happening.

[CODE]

```
- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {


//App activated due to file selection in an email attachment, display modal dialog
if (fileSelected) 
{
    RSAImportViewController *s = [[RSAImportViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RSAImportViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController* rNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:s];

    [rNC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [rNC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    [nav presentModalViewController:rNC animated:YES];

// wait for modal view to be dismissed, the modal view is dismissed when ok/cancel
// buttons are clicked.

  while (s.completion == requestRunning) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
}

[s dismissKeyboard];

// Do further processing

return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not what NSRunLoop methods are for.

You should instead set yourself as the delegate of your modal view and make the modal view inform its delegate when it is dismissed — and call any other method as appropriate to do anything you want to do.

In RSAImportViewController.h:

```
@class RSAImportViewController
@protocol RSAImportViewControllerDelegate
-(void)rsaImportViewControllerDone:(RSAImportViewController*)vc;
@end

@interface RSAImportViewController
...
@property(assign) id<RSAImportViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In RSAImportViewController.m, whereever you call the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method:

```
@implementation RSAImportViewController
@synthesize delegate;
...
-(void)someMethodInYourCode {
    ...
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // call the delegate method to inform we are done (adapt to your needs)
    [self.delegate rsaImportViewControllerDone:self];
}
...
@end
```

And in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
{
    if (fileSelected) {
        ...
        rNC.delegate = self; // set 'self' to be informed when the rNC is dismissed
        [nav presentModalViewController:rNC animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self doFurtherProcessing];
    }
}
-(void)rsaImportViewControllerDone:(RSAImportViewController*)vc {
    [self doFurtherProcessing];
}
-(void)doFurtherProcessing {
    [s dismissKeyboard];
    // and all your other stuff
}
```

Comment: Cool :) As I see ou're new to SO, if it solved you problem, don't forget to click on the checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as solved for others to know.